# When do I need waitForLedgerCommit

Tags: corda

In many example flows I see the following pattern:

```
// Notarises and records transaction
val stx = subFlow(FinalityFlow(signedTx))
waitForLedgerCommit(stx.id)
```

How exactly does the behavior of the system change when I add `waitForLedgerCommit` after `FinalityFlow`? Do I need to use this pattern in every flow or only in some?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`waitForLedgerCommit` suspends the flow until the transaction with the specified ID is received, successfully verified and sent to the vault for processing.

`FinalityFlow` verifies the given transaction then sends it to the named notary. If the notary agrees that the transaction is acceptable then it is from that point onwards committed to the ledger and will be written through to the vault.

If you take a look at the code in `FinalityFlow`, you'll see it calls the function `notariseAndRecord()` which in turn calls `serviceHub.recordTransactions()`. It's here we record the verified transaction to our vault.

If `FinalityFlow` completes successfully, we're guaranteed that the transaction has been verified and sent to the vault for processing, as such, we don't require `waitForLedgerCommit`.

Answer (score 2):

To add to Cais's answer, suppose you have a flow with two participants, Alice and Bob. Alice is invoking `FinalityFlow` on a transaction, and Bob then wants to perform an action once the transaction has been finalised.

Bob would call `waitForLedgerCommit` to wait for `FinalityFlow` to complete and record the transaction in his vault before performing an action.

In other words, you would generally see this used not by the party invoking `FinalityFlow`, but by the other parties to the flow.